# How to remove Projects (not jars) from EAR Libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, ear

To remove jars from the EAR, I just remove them from the EarContent/META-INF/lib folder. But how can I remove this **Projects** references from the EAR?

[image]

Comment: Did you get things working Tom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click the EAR application, select properties.  In the properties window, left side pane select "Deployment Assembly".  In the right pane, select the projects you'd like to remove and click the remove button.  However are you sure you want to do this?  You might note which are currently present in case it breaks things and you have to revert.  If you need to revert follow the same process but instead of clicking remove - click add and select "Projects" at the bottom.

Comment: Looks like it's not the case... I need the projects to be build and deployed, I just want them out of the EAR libs (like the other 10 referenced projects here).

Comment: all the projects are on the "Deployment Assembly", but only that five are in the EAR libs, so there must be somewhere else...

Comment: They'll only be placed in the EAR lib folder if a project references them.  For example I have a EAR, it includes an EJB jar and WAR projects.  The EJB and WAR projects both utilize numerous other libraries.  These libraries are listed in the EJB and WAR Deployment assembly properties setting - by doing this Eclipse knows that to bundle everything together and have the external libraries   accessible to the EJB and WAR it needs to add them to the EAR lib folder.  I may just be confused as to what you're trying to accomplish exactly.  How did you get that screen shot, an EAR has no build path?

Comment: Ahh, I see you're going to the properties of the WAR or EJB projects.  I dont believe you can remove those as that would break your project wouldn't it if those projects are required to make the entire EAR application function?

Comment: I wonder why only those 5? The other projects are added directly to the build path of each project that needs them. I think this 5 on the EAR are causing some of my cyclic dependencies here, as not everyone needs them.

Comment: Do you have things checked in the Order/Export tab - possibly thats causing the problem?

Comment: The "Order and Export" tab of each project have only the project itself. Also, I checked the .classpath and .project files, I can't find anything special about this 5 projects...

Comment: What about application.xml in the EAR META-INF folder, anything odd in there?

Comment: All the projects are listed in application.xml, in <ejb> tags, except this 5.

Comment: And the projects not listed in the application.xml do not have any project on their EAR Libraries. Only the jars. As I would like for every project.

Comment: Maybe not really important: All projects listed in the application.xml are EJBs, but 1, called "Conf". This utility project have those 5 listed on his EAR libs. I did remove it from the application.xml, restated, cleaned and rebuild everything, but nothing changed.

Comment: Hey, found! Those 5 are listed in Deployment Assembly with Deploy Path 'META-INF/lib/project.jar', all others are just 'project.jar'! Also, all the others are in the application.xml, and those 5 not. I'll do the tests here to fix.

Comment: Glad to see you're making progress!

Comment: Solved! that was it, the Deploy Path in Deployment Assembly

Comment: Sweet!  Glad you got it working and my answer helped even if just a little.  Thank you for accepting it!  have a great day Tom.